# How can I only pipe the stdout to another command, and redirecting stderr to the standard out of the terminal?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

I have a command `foo` whose `stdout` I want to pipe to another command `bar`, whose output I want to pipe to `bas`. If `foo` fails, I want to see it in the default standard out of the console. What is the best approach?

```bash
$ foo | bar | bas
```

For clarification, if `foo` fails with output in the stderr, I want to see it directly as a result, and not being processed by `bar` or `bas`.

```bash
$ foo | bar | bas
This is error written to stderr by foo.
```

Comment: `foo | bar` will only send `stdout` from `foo` to `bar`. `stderr` will go directly to the controlling terminal, so isn't it already working like you want it to work?

Comment: you can use xargs to provide the output of the first command (foo) as an input to second command (bar). If foo fails, the command will fail with the error message from the failed command (foo in this case).

Comment: The console doesn't "have" standard output  or standard error; it *is* the standard output *and* standard error of your ordinary interactive shell, which `foo` inherits for its own. The pipe means that `foo` uses the standard input of `bar` *instead* of the terminal for its standard output, but the standard error of `foo` remains unchanged: it's still the console.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that "foo" doesn't redirect stderr to stdout internally.

By default stderr is **NOT** routed to pipe.

You would only "lose" that stderr stream if you did either

```
foo 2>&1 | bar | bas
```

or

```
foo |& bar | bas
```